# Wildfly 10 list all deployed war artifacts by http management api

Tags: java, deployment, jenkins, jboss

Hi I've read the docs at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API

but I didn't find any information about listing already deployed artifacts. I would like to automate the deployment of artifacts in such way that I would be able to redeploy existing ones or deploy those which are not present yet. Is that possible with http api and usage of **curl**? I know it should be possible with **jboss-cli.sh** but I would prefer to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl --silent --digest http://user:password@localhost:9990/management --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"operation":"read-attribute","address":[{"deployment":"*"}], "name": "enabled", "json.pretty":1}'
```